# Display Two Tables with Separate SQL Query

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to display two tables, which have different sets of data displayed. The first table is just a single row displaying information about an invoice. The second table displays all the items contained in the invoice. Currently the page is displaying the first table correctly. The second table is where I am having issues. This table is showing all the data that I want. But it displays each item as a separate table, instead of rows within a table. Could someone take a look at my code, and possibly help me figure out where the srew up is at? Thanks

```
<?php

$storeid   = $_GET['store_id'];
$invoiceid = $_GET['invoice_id'];
$suppid    = $_GET['supp_id'];

$strSecReq     = '1';
$strDptReq     = 'ANY';
$strRequester  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/securelogin/logincheck.php");
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/database/database.php");

$pgtitle = "Invoice # " . $invoiceid . " Detail";

include('header.php');

$conn  = odbc_connect("$storeid", $ODBC_STOREID[1], $ODBC_STOREID[2]) or die ('<br><b>Error Connecting To STORE</b><br>\n');
```

**REMOVED SELECT STATEMENT PER COMPANY POLICY**

```
$rsSQL = odbc_exec($conn, $sql) or die ('<br>Error Executing detail SQL');

if (odbc_num_rows($rsSQL)== 0) {

   echo "<center>";
   echo "<br><b>Your Primary Item ID does not match any entries.<br>Please page back and try again.</b>";
   echo "</center>";

   odbc_close($conn);
} else {

   while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rsSQL)) {

      echo "<div align='center'>";
      echo "<table class ='tablesmall' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='4'>";
      echo "<thead>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<th><b>Supplier</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b>Control</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b>Type</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b>Inv Date</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b>Rec Date</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b># Lines</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b>Dept</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b>History</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b>Status</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b>Start TS</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b>End TS</b></th>";
      echo "<th><b>User</b></th>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</thead>";

      $SuppNum   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "SuppNum"));
      $ContNum   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "ContNum"));
      $InvType   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "InvType"));
      $InvDate   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "InvDate"));
      $RecDate   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "RecDate"));
      $NumLines  = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "NumLines"));
      $DeptNum   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "DeptNum"));
      $HistFlag  = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "HistFlag"));
      $InvStat   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "InvStat"));
      $InvStart  = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "InvStart"));
      $InvEnd    = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "InvEnd"));
      $UserName  = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL, "UserName"));

      echo "<tbody>";
      echo "<tr><td>";
      echo $SuppNum;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $ContNum;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $InvType;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $InvDate;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $RecDate;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $NumLines;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $DeptNum;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $HistFlag;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $InvStat;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $InvStart;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $InvEnd;
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $UserName;
      echo "</td></tr>";
      echo "</tbody>";
      echo "</table>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "<br>";
```

**REMOVED SELECT STATEMENT PER COMPANY POLICY**

```
      $rsSQL1 = odbc_exec($conn, $sql1) or die ('<br>Error Executing detail SQL');

      while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rsSQL1)) {

         echo "<div align='center'>";
         echo "<table class ='tablesmall' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='4'>";
         echo "<thead>";
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<th><b>Seq</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Type</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Ord Code</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>ItemID</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Sku Type</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Descr</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Pk Size</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>DeptNum</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Inv Units</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Qty</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>UM</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Price</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Multiple</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Pack</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Cost</b></th>";
         echo "<th><b>Allow</b></th>";
         echo "</tr>";
         echo "</thead>";

         $InvSEQ    = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "InvSEQ"));
         $IDTyp     = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "IDTyp"));
         $OrdCode   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "OrdCode"));
         $ItemID    = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "ItemID"));
         $SkuTyp    = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "SkuTyp"));
         $Descr     = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "Descr"));
         $PkSize    = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "PkSize"));
         $DeptNum   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "DeptNum"));
         $InvUnits  = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "InvUnits"));
         $FinQty    = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "FinQty"));
         $FinUM     = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "FinUM"));
         $FinPrice  = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "FinPrice"));
         $FinMult   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "FinMult"));
         $FinPack   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "FinPack"));
         $FinCost   = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "FinCost"));
         $FinAllow  = trim(odbc_result($rsSQL1, "FinAllow"));

         if ($bgcolor == '#ffffff') {

         $bgcolor = '#dddddd';
         } else {

         $bgcolor = '#ffffff';
         }

         echo "<tbody>";
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$InvSEQ</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$IDTyp</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$OrdCode</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$ItemID</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$SkuTyp</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$Descr</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$PkSize</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$DeptNum</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$InvUnits</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$FinQty</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$FinUM</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$FinPrice</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$FinMult</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$FinPack</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$FinCost</td>";
         echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align = 'center'>$FinAllow</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
         echo "</tbody>";
         echo "</table>";
         echo "</div>";

      }
   }

   odbc_close($conn);

   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/footer.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of this line:

`while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rsSQL) && $row2 = odbc_fetch_array($rsSQL1))`

By using this condition you are saying "loop while there's a record in the first recordset AND if there's also one in the second."

The problem is that your first recordset has only one record (the one of your invoice) and then makes the 1st condition evaluates to false after the 1st loop.

Solution: use a separate loop to show the invoice's items.

Comment: Alright, I believe I changed it to use a separate loop. I have changed my above code, to reflect the change I made. Now I get all the data I need in the second table, but it displays each one as its own table, instead of individual rows.

Comment: I separated the while{} and I moved the second select statement to just below the first. Now it looks like this:

Statement1
Statement2

While($row =fetch1){
Table1}

While($row1 = fetch2){
Table2}

Comment: Awesome, so after doing what you suggested, I was able to get everything to display. But it was only giving a table for the first row, then the rest was just text on the page. I figured that one out, I had the </tbody></table> in the second while loop so it was closing the table after the first row. Thank you for your help.